# How to create multiple mysql tables with MySQLdb in python?

Tags: python, mysql-python

This is what i am trying to do:

```
cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE testing")
cursor.execute("USE testing")
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE Contract(mEnd varchar(7))")    
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE User(uName varchar(15)")
```

When I run the python script using MySQLdb it only creates the first table and it ignores all the other lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

`)` is missing in your last statement. Though you really don't want to do it this way.

Comment: If this is the reason, why `Contract` is not being created according to the OP?

Comment: @iced what would be a better approach?

Comment: "but when I run the python script it only creates the first table and it ignores all the other lines of code." (c) (tm). and yes, this is the reason. As mysql isn't real database, virtually all libs are configuring autocommit by default.

Comment: seems dead. well, anyway, statement's true - pick up any migration framework you fancy and use it.

Comment: FYI, `south` is there specifically for django projects and it became a base for the Django migration framework introduced in 1.7 - which is why it is dying.

Comment: well - anyway - as I see "Contract" and "User" and... well... quality of the code, I can bet money on the guess he is doing Yet Another Corporate Web Portal or smth. As all other python frameworks are even worse and/or way harder to use, I can also bet some money that he is or will be using django. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
execute = ["CREATE DATABASE testing","USE testing","CREATE TABLE Contract(mEnd varchar(7))","CREATE TABLE User(uName varchar(15))"]
for i in execute:
    cussor.execute(i)
    cussor.commit()
```